# Getting the source .exe file name from .lnk shortcut in batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have to extract source filename from .lnk shortcut in batch. The extracted text must be in (program name).(extension) form.

I must admit that I'm a complete laic, when it comes to batch (or any scripting actually), so any help concerning my question is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to do it in shell script (batch)? It's much simpler in PowerShell.

Comment: I'm doing a one-time assignment, which I'm unfortunately too deep into to switch to PowerShell (in which I have absolutely no experience).

Comment: You would need to extract the metadata from the .lnk file to do this. This is not trivial in batch, but very easy in a VBScript/JScript script or PowerShell.

Comment: If the batch file can open the VBScript, then this is not a problem. The outcome has to come back to batch though. My script would be quite tangled, but as for now, only the outcome matters.
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: As you can see from the reply from rojo, a "pure" shell script solution is pretty painful (requires slow WMIC). A VBS solution would probably be faster and easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a `wmic` query to [win32_shortcutfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Just make sure all your backslashes are backslash-escaped within `%filename%`.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

:: ensure user supplied a filename with a .lnk extension
if /i "%~x1" neq ".lnk" (
    echo usage: %~nx0 shortcut.lnk
    goto :EOF
)

:: set filename to the fully qualified path + filename
set "filename=%~f1"

:: convert single backslashes to double
set "filename=%filename:\=\\%"

:: get target
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('wmic path win32_shortcutfile where "name='%filename%'" get target /format:list ^| find "="') do (
    echo(%%J
)
```

What you want ends up in `%%J`.  If you only want the target `filename.ext`, change that to `%%~nxJ`.  If you want only the drive and path, change it to `%%~dpJ`.  See the last page of `help for` in a cmd console for more info about variable expansion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now I'll try and implement that into my puzzle.

Comment: I know this thread is ancient but how do you run this code when the link is on a server? Instead of C:\myLink.lnk I have \\myServer\myLink.lnk
The code gives the error "No Instance(s) Available."